# how to combine and form a complex data frame in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a data frame named `df` in the following format:

```
       match_up     result
0   1985_1116_1234      1
1   1985_1120_1345      1
2   1985_1207_1250      1
3   1985_1229_1425      1
```

I have another data frame called `df1`

```
  team       win percentage     sum_of_last_six  seed_frequency
0  1116           0.700                5               7
1  1234           0.667                3              10
2  1120           0.636                4               9
3  1207           0.615                2              11
4  1229           0.345                2               3
5  1345           0.621                5              11
6  1425           0.572                1               2
7  1250           0.968                4              12
```

I need to form 2 new data frames named `df2` and `df3` in such a way that `df2` includes all the left side values(succeeding after 1985_) of the column `matchup` in dataframe `df` ie. `1116, 1120, 1207, 1229`. `df3` should have the values in the right side of `matchup` column.

```
  team_df2        win_df2           sum_df2       seed_df2
0  1116           0.700                5               7
1  1120           0.636                4               9
2  1207           0.615                2              11
3  1229           0.345                2               3

   team_df3       win_df3           sum_df3       seed_df3
1  1234           0.667                3              10
5  1345           0.621                5              11
7  1250           0.968                4              12
6  1425           0.572                1               2
```

at the end I need a new data frame that combines the three data frames (`df`, `df2` and `df3`)

I need to form a new data frame called  `combi` in following format:

```
      match_up      result  team_df2   win_df2  sum_df2  seed_df2  
  0 1985_1116_1234      1      1116      0.700      5        7
  1 1985_1120_1345      1      1120      0.636      4        9 
  2 1985_1207_1250      1      1207      0.615      2        11
  3 1985_1229_1425      1      1229      0.345      2        3

     team_df3       win_df3           sum_df3       seed_df3
      1234           0.667                3              10
      1345           0.621                5              11
      1250           0.968                4              12
      1425           0.572                1               2
```

How do I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the vectorised `str` method on the 'match_up' column to split the string, map these to int and create a list so we can filter the second df on to create df2 and df3:

```
In [90]:

left = list(map(int,(df['match_up'].str.split('_').str[1])))
right = list(map(int,(df['match_up'].str.split('_').str[2])))
print(left)
right
[1116, 1120, 1207, 1229]
Out[90]:
[1234, 1345, 1250, 1425]
In [91]:

df2 = df1[df1.win.isin(left)]
df2
Out[91]:
   team   win  percentage  sum_of_last_six  seed_frequency
0     0  1116       0.700                5               7
2     2  1120       0.636                4               9
3     3  1207       0.615                2              11
4     4  1229       0.345                2               3
In [92]:

df3 = df1[df1.win.isin(right)]
df3
Out[92]:
   team   win  percentage  sum_of_last_six  seed_frequency
1     1  1234       0.667                3              10
5     5  1345       0.621                5              11
6     6  1425       0.572                1               2
7     7  1250       0.968                4              12
```

if needed you can rename the columns calling `rename`.

To get the merged output df you want with the renamed columns:

```
In [95]:

df2 = df2.rename(columns={'team':'team_df2', 'win':'win_df2', 'sum_of_last_six':'sum_df2', 'seed_frequency':'seed_df2'})
df3 = df3.rename(columns={'team':'team_df3', 'win':'win_df3', 'sum_of_last_six':'sum_df3', 'seed_frequency':'seed_df3'})
In [101]:

pd.concat([df,df2,df3],axis=1)
Out[101]:
         match_up  result  team_df2  win_df2  percentage  sum_df2  seed_df2  \
0  1985_1116_1234       1         0     1116       0.700        5         7   
1  1985_1120_1345       1       NaN      NaN         NaN      NaN       NaN   
2  1985_1207_1250       1         2     1120       0.636        4         9   
3  1985_1229_1425       1         3     1207       0.615        2        11   
4             NaN     NaN         4     1229       0.345        2         3   
5             NaN     NaN       NaN      NaN         NaN      NaN       NaN   
6             NaN     NaN       NaN      NaN         NaN      NaN       NaN   
7             NaN     NaN       NaN      NaN         NaN      NaN       NaN   

   team_df3  win_df3  percentage  sum_df3  seed_df3  
0       NaN      NaN         NaN      NaN       NaN  
1         1     1234       0.667        3        10  
2       NaN      NaN         NaN      NaN       NaN  
3       NaN      NaN         NaN      NaN       NaN  
4       NaN      NaN         NaN      NaN       NaN  
5         5     1345       0.621        5        11  
6         6     1425       0.572        1         2  
7         7     1250       0.968        4        12
```

Comment: perfect answer. so I can use merge to merge these 3 data frames right . but what would be the `on` value while merging?

Comment: You want to see df1, df2 and df3 merged so they are side by side?

Comment: I want them merged and I have mentioned the column format in the question.

Comment: I've added code that performs the renaming and merging

Comment: Sorry I couldnt reply you immediately as we are in different time zones. I have edited the question. The `combi` data frame is a single data frame with 10 columns. how do I do that?